# How to add “selection” styles to a new element while deselecting the previous element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

There are two windows. One is responsible for displaying data, and the second for working with it (deleting, changing, adding)

```
const [active, setActive] = React.useState(null);    
..............

 <FirstWindow active = {active}  setActive = {setActive}></FirstWindow>         
 <SecondWindow active = {active}  setActive = {setActive}></SecondWindow>
```

Inside the first window there is implemented the addition of a "selection" of the element that was clicked. (there can be only one selected element, clicked on another, the selection is gone from the past, added to a new one)

```
const FirstWindow = ({items, active, setActive}) =>{
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    function getElem(i, item) {          
        setActive(i);        
        dispatch(userInfo(item));     
    }

    
    return(
        <div className = "container">
            {
                items.items.map((item,i) =>{
                    return <FirstWindowItems
                     item = {item}
                     isActive={active===i}
                     onClick={()=>getElem(i,item)}
                     key={item.id}
                     
                     ></FirstWindowItems>
                })
            }            
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
class SecondWindow extends React.Component{
    constructor(props, active, setActive){
        super(props);
        this.active = active;
        this.setActive = setActive;
    }

ubmitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault();        

        const newUser = {
            id: Date.now().toString(),
            FIO: "name",
            position:"Position",
            birthDay: "date",
            sex: true,
            fired: false
        };        
        this.props.createNewUser(newUser);
        this.props.userInfo(newUser);
        this.setActive(1); //here
    }
```

The second window has a button for adding a new item. When you click on this button, it is required to add selection styles to this element and deselect the previous selection. how to do it? I am using redux, maybe it could be implemented through it?

Comment: [Lift state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the component that renders first and second window. That means you declare active and setActive in the parent of first and second window.

Comment: @HMR 
I tried to do this, but got an error, now I will try again :)

Comment: @HMR I did like this, look, I changed the code inside the question.
how should it look inside submitHandler?

Comment: Put active and setActive on props so send window can do `this.props.setActive`